# SQS Poll deletes messages upon reading

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using SQS service in my application which pushes jobs to the queue based on client request.

I have the following polling mechanism setup in a separate job server.

```
    def get_message(self):
        response = self.queue.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=self.sqs_endpoint_url,
            AttributeNames=['All'],
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            MaxNumberOfMessages=self.max_messages_per_read,
            WaitTimeSeconds=self.wait_time,
        )
        if response and ('Messages' in response) and (len(response["Messages"]) > 0):
            return response['Messages'][0]
        return None


def poll()
    while True:
        try:
           message = self.get_message()
           if message is None:
               time.sleep(self.sleep_time_if_no_messages_found)
           else:
               config.logger.info(f'Processing message {message}')
               action(message)
               message_receipt_handle = message["ReceiptHandle"]
               self.delete_message(message_receipt_handle)
            except Exception:
                config.logger.error(f'Error in processing message from queue: {str(traceback.format_exc())}')


// From job server
poll()
```

From the logs I observed that the messages are pushed to the queue, but it receives just one message and rest of the messages are just deleted without ever calling the action() method.

I'm pretty new to SQS and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The polling takes place in a single thread.

SQS Attributes set,

```
ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
VisibilityTimeout: 300
MaxReceiveCount: 5
```

Comment: What is the value of self.max_messages_per_read ? If greater than 1, you are reading multiple messages, but only processing one. These messages will be invisible during the visibility timeout, in this case 5 minutes. After 5 minutes they should come back and at this point one more message will be processed. You also don't need to time.sleep in your main loop, as the WaitTimeSeconds=self.wait_time is already doing this for you.

Comment: @mananony I have the `self.max_messages_per_read` set to 1. But from the logs I can clearly see that it's processing one message but deleting the rest of the messages.

Comment: how do you know the messages are deleted ? Is your program just looping while waiting ? What does the AWS console tell you ? Normally a message is deleted in one of two cases: You delete it, or it gets sent to the dead letter queue after a number of failed attempts.

Comment: Maybe another service is also polling your queue ? Like AWS lambda or something ?

Comment: I have a log message in `self.delete_message` which tells me that the message has been deleted. @mananony

Comment: I just have a `worker` and `job` service running. There might be a number of `job` service instances running, though.

Comment: It's just that I'm facing an inconsistent behavior, sometimes it works alright but other times it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `get_message()` to return 10 messages (maximum) instead of 1 and modified `poll()` to iterate over the messages and now it seems to be working alright.